# Laravel : change the contents of the variable with the database field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have code Laravel 
in code i have variable $latitude1 and longitude1, and this variable have static conten like '108.2251681'.

```
$maps = Gmaps_Geocache::all();

        $latitude1 = -7.325374900000001;    
        $longitude1 = 108.2251681;

        $latitude2 = -7.331842799999999;        
        $longitude2 = 108.2237382;

        $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude1.",".$longitude1."&destinations=".$latitude2.",".$longitude2."&key=AIzaSyCyUBu8OPh0adMWbL9McFMMDqJA9UB7jes");
```

how to change the contents '108.2251681' of the variable and immediately take from the field database?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  You want to use value from database instead of static value?  Like maybe `$map = Gmaps_Geochache::find(1); $longitude1 = $map->longitude;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was solve it, i put it in view blade

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Latitude</th>
                <th>Longitude</th>
                <th>Jarak</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($maps as $m)
            <tr>
                    @php
                        $latitude1 = -7.325374900000001;;   
                        $longitude1 = 108.2251681;

                        $latitude2 = $m->latitude;      
                        $longitude2 = $m->longitude;

                        $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude1.",".$longitude1."&destinations=".$latitude2.",".$longitude2."&key=AIzaSyCyUBu8OPh0adMWbL9McFMMDqJA9UB7jes");

                        $json = json_decode($dataJson);
                        $nilaiJarak = $json->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
                    @endphp
                <td>{{ $m->address }}</td>
                <td>{{ $m->latitude }}</td>
                <td>{{ $m->longitude }}</td>
                <td>{{ $nilaiJarak }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
```